# What does SQL dollar sign followed by curly braces

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am currently looking at a SQL query and in multiple places I see something like the following:

```
select * from Customer
where
    product = '${product_name}'
    order = '${order_num}'
```

I have been searching the internet but did not find anything relevant here. Can someone help what this command means in SQL and what is called?

Note: I have also seen it in hive query.

Comment: That isn't valid T-SQL. If you've seen in in T-SQL then it's presumably in application code and is a form of injection and is a *major* security vulnerability.

Comment: Can it be in sparkSQL or Hive?

Comment: This looks like rather typical variable substitution. It's not a part of SQL language per se; most likely like the actual substitution happens in the midlayer code (the code that calls SQL Server). Where do those variables come from - impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: I can't answer for either of those, but I would personally suggest that it looks like application style injection.

Comment: I have seen this notation before and I was confused as well. @SevaAlekseyev, mentioned it is not part of SQL languange, what language can have this? is spark or Hive that OP mentined have such syntax.

Comment: We would be better off knowing what language the OP *actually* saw it in, @stack . As both myself and Seva are guessing, they have seen this in application code, and we don't know what language it is that was written in. Ideally, we need the full snippet the syntax is from, not a couple of lines that could be from *any* language.

Comment: @Larnu, I added the query, it looks like a standard SQL query. it seems I should initialize the order_num and product_name

Comment: I asked for the full code, @user59419 . Where is that query being run? Where is the rest of the code that defines your values? That query would never compile in any SQL because even *if* `'${product_name}'` were a valid variable reference, it hasn't been defined.

Comment: This looks like it's coming from a shell script.